# Serialize an array into JSON objects using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

The serialization of the array returns the following JSON:

```
[{"Code":"AAAA","Description":"Description of AAAA"},{"Code":"BBBB","Description":"Description of BBBB"}]
```

My goal is to return the following JSON:

```
{"AAAA":{"Description":"Description of AAAA"},"BBBB":{"Description":"Description of BBBB"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve something **simliar** (not exactly the same you are expecting) if instead of serializing an array, build a temporary Dictionary and serialize it.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<String, YourClass>();
foreach (YourClass yourObj in listOfObjs)
{
    dict[yourObj.Code] = yourObj;
}
// then serialize "dict"
```

You could add a rule to your JSON serializer to make it avoid serializing "code" property in `YourClass`, and you will end up with a JSON object **exactly** as you show in your example.

Comment: Or just make an object representing the serialized target (leaving the original app object alone).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to either use a class that has the "AAAA" and "BBBB" properties, or you'll need to serialize a dictionary instead. As it is, you're serializing an array and getting an array.

Answer (score 0):

The table on [this blog post](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) shows several search starting points.

.Net has built-in System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer, [here, with examples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx)

The .Net one doesn't specially serialize Dictionary the way you want, but some of the others do, I believe.  However, I think there are reasons NOT to want a general serialization routine the way you've requested - though I can't list them certainly.