# Formatting a Json.NET Jarray to a String in a certain way

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have the following code which is looping through a raw_coords JSON.NET JArray object.

```
List<string> coords_final = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in raw_coords.Children())
{
    var itemcount = item.Count();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemcount; i++) //loop through rows
    {
        var coord_temp1 = item[i].ToString();
        coord_temp1 = coord_temp1.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', ',', '.' });
        coord_temp1 = coord_temp1.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '[', '.' });
        coord_temp1 = coord_temp1.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', ']', '.' });
        coord_temp1 = coord_temp1.Replace(',', ' ');
        coords_final.Add(coord_temp1);
    }
}
```

In the above loop, the value of the `item` variable is something like:

```
item [ [    -9221176.0728999991,    4120407.4526000023  ],  [    -9221176.0427000001,    4120407.6987999976  ]],[[...],[]]
```

And, in the data above, the `coords_final` does become an array with two elements. But what I **need is one string variable which will have data in the form of**:

```
(-9221176.0729 4120407.4526000023, -9221176.0427 4120407.6987999976), (..)..
```

My code above is adapted from another C# program but the data that currently yields is like:

```
-9221176.0729 4120407.4526000023, -9221176.0427 4120407.6987999976, -9221176.1341 4120407.4602999985,
```

which is not what I need.

So how can I make the data to be in the desired format--as shown above? I have tried to prepend "(" and append ")" but that didn't work.

Comment: Appending and prepending the parens should work fine.  Can you post the code that didn't work and explain what happened?

Comment: Hmmm. The code deleted--basically, I was ending up with an extra comma at the very end but, as you can see, my code is trying to also remove a comma

Comment: There might be a better approach to this over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096474/serialize-an-array-into-json-objects-using-net .  Instead of string building, build a dictionary and then use a serializer on it to get proper json without the string parsing mess.

Comment: Yes, but I am very close: the 'item' variable is currently populating the coords_final list string. What it needs to do is to input all item variable's data into one element of coords_final with the ( and ) attached.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I didn't mean to include 'C#' as a tag in the title: It was to draw attention to the programming environment. Was that wrong?

Comment: @Meengla - yes, it clutters the title without providing any more information. After all, your question is tagged "C#".

Comment: Okay. Will watch out next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `raw_coords` is your Jarray

```
List<string> myCoordsList = new List<string>();

foreach(JToken item in raw_coords)
{
    List<string> listOfPairs = new List<string>();
    var result = item.ToObject<JArray>();
    foreach (JToken jToken in result)
    {
        var jarray = (JArray) jToken;
        IEnumerable<string> nums = jarray.Values<string>();
        listOfPairs.Add(string.Join(" ", nums));
    }

    myCoordsList.Add(string.Format("({0})", string.Join(",", listOfPairs)));
}
string coordsString = string.Join(",", myCoordsList);
```

the result is

```
(-9221176.0729 4120407.4526),(-9221176.0427 4120407.6988),(-9221176.1341 4120407.4603),(-9221176.0729 4120407.4526),(-9221176.104 4120407.7063),(-9221176.1341 4120407.4603) ...
```

for the first few pairs of coords.

Comment: Did you mean to Deserialize the raw_coords array?

Comment: oh... now i see... item contains the rows... i'll update my answer (deserialize item[i]...)

Comment: Thanks. Let me try again. BTW, I did Deserialize the loaded JSON in a few lines of code above...not sure if that will have any bearing.

Comment: I don't think your code is going to work as it is given: There is already the foreach encompassing your code: foreach (var item in raw_coords.Children())

Comment: well it should when your `item[i]` is in the form of `[ [    -9221176.0728999991,    4120407.4526000023  ],  [    -9221176.0427000001,    4120407.6987999976  ]],[[...],[]]`

Comment: Says invalid arguments at: var result = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(item[i]);

Comment: maybe it works with `(JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(item[i].ToString())`?

Comment: No, same: Invalid arguments.

Comment: could you tell me what `item[i]` exactly is when you debug it?

Comment: And please note: Item for each entity is like: [    -9221176.0728999991,    4120407.4526000023  ],  [    -9221176.0427000001,    4120407.6987999976  ]]

Comment: could you post the entire json?

Comment: The item variable, in the data given, has two arrays

Comment: could you post the entire json?

Comment: Yes, working on posting the entire  JSON; ...it is big so will give a link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72281/discussion-between-meengla-and-stefankmitph).

Answer (score 0):

The following solution gives the result you want:

```
string json = @"[ 
    [    -9221176.0728999991,    4120407.4526000023  ],  
    [    -9221176.0427000001,    4120407.6987999976  ]
 ]";

JArray raw_coords = JArray.Parse(json);
List<string> coords_final = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in raw_coords.Children())
{
    coords_final.Add("("+String.Join<object>(",", item)+")");
}

string coords = String.Join(",",coords_final.ToArray());

Console.WriteLine (coords);
```

---

(-9221176.0729,4120407.4526),(-9221176.0427,4120407.6988)

Comment: Thanks! Never got around to trying your solution but sure appreciate your help.